# Is first-order logic a sufficiently powerful metatheory to prove the "conditional independence" of CH from ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Lets define independence and conditional independence as follows.

1. Define that an axiom $X$ is independent from a system $Y$ if and only if $Y$ can be used to prove neither $X$, nor its (syntactical) negation $\mathop{\sim}X$. That is, $X$ is independent from $Y$ if and only if $\neg(Y \vdash X) \wedge \neg(Y \vdash \mathop{\sim}X).$
2. Define that an axiom $X$ is conditionally independent from an axiom system $Y$ precisely when the consistency of $Y$ implies that $X$ is independent of $Y$. That is, $X$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ precisely when $\neg(Y \vdash \bot) \Rightarrow \neg(Y \vdash X) \wedge \neg(Y \vdash \mathop{\sim} X).$

Is first-order logic a sufficiently powerful metatheory to prove the conditional independence of CH from ZFC? My quess would be "no" because ZFC is not finitely axiomtizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw first-order logic *itself* is not a useful metatheory.

However, the usual conditional consistency proofs can be formalized in a metatheory consisting of ZF running on ordinary first-order logic. I think PA (also on first-order logic) will also suffice.

Comment: Well it may not be very useful from a practical perspective, but my question is about the existence of a proof, not about practical convenience. For instance, suppose we have a proof of the conditional independence of CH from ZFC in the system PA. Can we use this proof to obtain a proof in the system FOL?

Comment: @user18921: My point is that you can't even _express_ the properties you're speaking about in pure FOL without any proper axioms. _Proving_ them is completely moot, then. You might be able to cheat and represent a computable function by, say, $Q\to \phi(x,y)$ where $Q$ is the conjunction of the finitely many axioms of Robinson arithmetic and $\phi(x,y)$ is the standard arithmetical representation of the function in question -- but then you're not really working in raw FOL anyway; you're just working in Q while pretending you're not. (Or the same for NBG set theory instead of Q).

Comment: Oh. I see. Is PA the "minimal" metatheory in which the conditional independence of (say) CH from ZFC can be expressed?

Comment: @user18921: PA cannot be minimal, because it is not finitely axiomatized. If you prove your result from PA, the proof will use a finite subset of the axioms, and the theory consisting of that finite subset will be smaller than PA but still able to prove the result.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you recommend an easy introductory book about consistency, independence etc.